# android ListView size of every child

Tags: android, listview

I am populating a `ListView` using my custom adapter as I need to do some special formatting on every TextView that I send over. The problem is that no matter how small I set the textSize of each TextView, they are separated by the same amount of space in the list as shown in the image

[image]

I want the spacing between these views reduced. This is my getView() method.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setText( getItem(position).getName() );
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);
        textView.setTextColor( getItem(position).getClr() );
        return textView;
    }
```

edit1:
What I want actually is that "Blue" and "Green" should be closer together. I want to reduce the spacing between them.

edit2:
xml:

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/answerlist"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/question" >

        </ListView>
```

Comment: The text sizes all look the same in the image you posted above. Also, posting your xml files will be helpful.

Comment: the whole xml file is quite large so I have put in the listView part. @prolink007 see the edit

Comment: Try setting the layout_height of the row to wrap_content. I have done that only with xml, so in your case, I don't know but that can be a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... The problem was that I was using the default layout android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 to generate views for rows of the ListView. This layout uses the text appearance "?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge". I dont know what kind of padding/margins this sets but no matter what I do in the adapter, the spacing did not reduce.

So what I did was that I made a custom xml layout named "row.xml" in res/layout and put a simple TextView in there. I used this layout to inflate rows in my ListView and the space was gone. Here is the code of the constructor:

```
public ColoredAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ColorElement> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.row, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is because of the following line:

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

By d way what you need actually can you explain me in detail?

Answer (score 0):

As jyotiprakash mentioned it may need to give a more detailed description of what you are trying to do.

However, from what I can see you are trying to set the margin. If so I would go about it in the following way.

```
    .....
    View someView = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.yourViewLayout, null, false);

    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layoutParams.setMargins(4, 15, 4, 0);

    //Now you can use your view to set the layout params
    someView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Now the margin for that view will be in line with the above defined layout params

Comment: Well.. I dont know how I can explain it even further. But lemme try... As you can see in the image I posted, the first text is "Blue", then there is a lot of space, then there is the divider and after another lot of space, there is the text "Green". I want to reduce this amount of space that is there between every TextView and  divider.